# Keyboard Not Captured on VirtualBox OS X

Tags: virtualbox, osx-elcapitan

I have installed El Capitan on Virtual Box 5.1.28. However, the laptop keyboard isn't working even though the auto capture icon is turned on. When I use an external keyboard, that works. But I want to use my native laptop keyboard. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem, I learned that installing macOS on VMWare does not have this keyboard problem. Instructions are [here](https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-high-sierra-vmware-windows/)